# Spring MVC java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have commented below session in the dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping": Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] for bean with name org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0 defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; 
    nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] for bean with name
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping 
        Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception 
        is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
```

```xml
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    
          <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
          <groupId>com.mansal.ose</groupId>
          <artifactId>mansal-web</artifactId>
          <packaging>war</packaging>
          <version>1.0</version>
          <name>Mansal Webapp</name>
          <dependencies>
    
        <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.0</spring.version> 
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId> 
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId> 
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId> 
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId> 
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId> 
        <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>concurrent</groupId> 
        <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId> 
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version> 
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId> 
        <version>4.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId> 
        <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId> 
        <artifactId>ant1r4-runtime</artifactId> 
        <version>4.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
    
        <build>
        <finalName>mansal</finalName>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source> 
        <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>
        </project>
```

I am using Spring MVC version 4, Tomcat version 8.5 and Maven

While compiling my project I am getting below error message

```
    SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class [org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher] 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
```

Attached error message and web.xml
Could you please help how to fix this issue.

```
        INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARS that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded
    
        JARS during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 
    
        Apr 30, 2021 11:38:34 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARS that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARS during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    
        Apr 30, 2021 11:38:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: No Spring WebApplication Initializer types detected on classpath 
        Apr 30, 2021 11:38:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    
        SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class [org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher] 
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365) 
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager java:540) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.Default InstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged (DefaultInstanceManager.java:521) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4612) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start Internal(StandardContext.java:5151) 
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.exe execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:134) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Abstract ExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) 
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal (StandardService.java:421) 
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) 
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java: 343) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
```

```xml
        <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
        <display-name>MANSAL</display-name> <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Index.html</welcome-file> 
        </welcome-file-list>
        <display-name>MANSAL</display-name>
        <description>MANSAL</description>
    
    
        <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.Configurelistener</listener-class>
        </listener>
    
        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
    
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    
        <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param value>
        </context-param>
    
        <listener>
        <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
    
        <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
        </listener>
    
        <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
    
        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
    
        <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
        </session-config>
    
        <error-page>
        <error-code>404></error-code>
        <location>/webpages/error.jsp</location>
        </error-page>
    
        <listener>
        <listener-class>com.mansal.web.CleanUpSessionListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
    
        </<web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.mansal.controller"/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.mansal.ose"/>
    
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.servlet.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
    
    
        <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
    
        <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
        <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mansal.v2.PooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <!-- these are connection pool properties -->
            <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
            <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
        </bean>
    
    </beans>
```

Comment: Can you add your project's dependencies to your question? You have a missing dependency (probably `spring-security-web`).

Comment: I already have the spring-security-web dependency in the project, attached the dependencies.

Comment: Then check if `spring-security-web-*.jar` was physically copied to the deployed application.

Comment: I have the existing servlet developed in sping mvc 3.x shall I need to place the 3.x spring-security-web jar file or the spring-security-web 4.x in the physical (WEB-INF/LIB) path?

Comment: The file should already be there, when you create a WAR file or deploy the project to the server. However, when developing with Eclipse, I have experienced several times that some libraries where not copied, so it is better to check.

Comment: Thank you, I am able to solve HttpSessionEventPublisher. During the compilation I am getting different compilation error message from dispatcher-servlet.xml.  Since DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping is deprecated, I have changed from DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping to RequestMappingHandlerMapping in xml file but still I see ClassNotFoundException error message. Have attached the error message.